# execute a gradle task from inside a docker file

Tags: docker, gradle

I am new to docker and I need help to figure this out.
I have a project with sub projects and I am creating a docker image for one of the sub project. My end goal is to execute the gradle task from the docker container. Is this possible?

Here is what I am trying to achieve. I want to call a task defined in the build.gradle  from inside a docker file
Here is the task which I want to execute  and the task docker inside my build.gradle

```
task mytestTask(type: JUnitHarnessRunnerTask) {
  //some task that needs to be executed
}

docker {
  String version = project.getVersion()

  name "${componentDockerImageName}:${version}"
  dockerfile file('Dockerfile')

  buildArgs(['ARTIFACT_NAME'   : 'my-tests-module',
             'ARTIFACT_VERSION': version,
             'ARTIFACT_FILE'   : "my-tests-module-" + version + ".jar",
             'BASE_IMAGE'      : componentDockerBaseImage,
             'COMPONENT'       : 'my-tests-module'])
  files project.libsDir
  dependsOn tasks.build
}
```

---

//Here is my docker file

```
ARG     BASE_IMAGE
FROM    ${BASE_IMAGE}

USER    root
RUN     yum --assumeyes install unzip

WORKDIR /gradle

RUN     curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip -o gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip
RUN     unzip gradle-5.6.4-bin.zip
ENV     GRADLE_HOME=/gradle/gradle-5.6.4
ENV     PATH=$PATH:${GRADLE_HOME}/bin
ARG     ARTIFACT_FILE
ENV     MY_COMPONENT="${COMPONENT}"
ENV     MY_COMPONENT_ROOT="${MY_APP_ROOT}/${COMPONENT}"
ENV     MY_ARTIFACT="${MY_COMPONENT_ROOT}/${ARTIFACT_FILE}"
COPY    --chown=admin:mydir ${ARTIFACT_FILE} ${MY_ARTIFACT}
USER    admin

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN     gradle --version

RUN     gradle my-tests-module:mytestTask
```

This is the error I am getting when I build ./gradlew my-tests-module:Docker
Project 'my-tests-module' not found in root project 'tmp'.

I am able to see gradle --version
when I do RUN gradle tasks --all , it is not listing out all the tasks which I have given inside my build.gradle

How can I get the docker file to run my gradle task. How do I copy all the necessary files to run the gradle task.right now, I am only copying the jar.
I cannot share the base image details but everything works and executes till gradle --version command and it correctly displays the gradle version.